# python replace sort using lambda key with sort()

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, lambda

How can I replace the following code written in python3 with normal `sort()` function?

```
    list = sorted(list, key=lambda x: x['result'], reverse=True)
```

NOTE: `x['result']` is int

Comment: In the future, please explain what you mean by things like "the normal sort() function". It would be more helpful to say something like "the list.sort() method" for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do exactly the same thing using `list.sort()`, i.e it takes in a "key" argument,
all you have to do is to change the function call on `position_list` into a method call.

For example:

```
l.sort(key=lambda x: x["result"], reverse=True)
```

As far as the `lambda` is concerned, you can just substitute it with a real function instead, but I don't think anything else can be simpler than a lambda.

P.S: Have a look at the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort

Comment: Add examples instead of only documentations, I already read that before

Answer (score 0):

Use: `competition_list.sort(key=lambda x: x['result'], reverse=reversed_order)`. It sorts the list in place.

Comment: My question was not to use lambda but normal sort function